# How do I print a whole string with multiple lines at a specific column?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, bios, ascii-art

This is my code:

```
data segment

     letter_a db   '  __ _  ',10,13
              db   ' / _` | ',10,13
              db   '| (_| | ',10,13
              db   ' \__,_| ',10,13
              db   '        '                                  
    opening_end db 0             
    pointer db 10         

ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    call print_opening

    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    call print_opening

    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

proc print_opening   
    pusha

    mov al, 1 
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, 3 

    ; I calculate length
    lea cx, opening_end   
    lea dx, letter_a
    sub cx, dx               

    mov dh, 3 ; row
    mov dl, [pointer] ; col
    lea bp, letter_a                           

    mov ah, 13h
    int 10h              

    mov ah, 8
    int 21h

    add [pointer], 10
    popa
    ret
endp print_opening

end start
```

The problem is it only starts the first line of the string in my chosen column and then goes back to column zero. Is there a way to indent the whole string whenever I want to?
I want to be able to change it as I am in my code, and not just set the indentation in the data segment.
I really hope this is possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useless to have linefeed and carriage return in the data lines given that a loop is required to pull this off.

```
letter_a    db   '  __ _  '
            db   ' / _` | '
            db   '| (_| | '
            db   ' \__,_| '
            db   '        '
opening_end db   0             
pointer     db   10
```

The loop will end as soon as it reads the terminating 0 at *opening_end*.

```
    mov     cx, 8     ; Every row has 8 characters
    mov     dh, 3     ; row on the screen to start
    mov     dl, [pointer] ; col on the screen is fixed
    lea     bp, letter_a
Again:
    mov     bx, 0003h ; display page 0 and attribute 03h
    mov     ax, 1301h ; function 13h and write mode 1
    int     10h
    add     bp, cx    ; To next line in the data
    inc     dh        ; To next row on the screen
    cmp     [es:bp], ch  ; CH=0
    jne     Again
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your reply, however, I ran your code and it still only shows to the first row of the string, and now the rest isn't in the first column it's just isn't there.

Comment: @SurfingSky The `cm [bp], ch` was using the `SS:` segment but your data is at `ES:`. Corrected!

Comment: sorry if i'm annoying but now it just shows wrong parameter error,

Comment: @SurfingSky It's possible you have to use an alternative syntax like `cmp es:[bp], ch` or have `ES:` on a separate line. If needed consult the assembler's manual.

Comment: thank you so much, you just saved my school project (as you can tell assembly is not my go-to language) thank you!

Comment: @SurfingSky Always a pleasure to be able to help.